# Oracle Apex Textarea - Apperance -Template "Required" should remain Placeholder value when user typing

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-apex-19.1

Hello Oracle Apex Experts,
I've a strange scenario. When a user is typing a text in the textarea, placeholder value should remain or move up and the red coloured asterisk (*) should remain for the label as screenshotted below. I know this can be achieved with the combo of HTML, CSS and JS but not sure how can I use this for a textarea in Oracle apex? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UfOW.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can work a little bit on your description :-)

In APEX 5.1 you will need to build your own template (you don't need JS, CSS is enough - https://css-tricks.com/float-labels-css/).

APEX 18 and above implements the floating template (Universal Theme) by the default - use floating template.